# $n$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^ni^k$ for all $k=1,2,...,99$ Prove that $n$ isn't divisible by any number in $\{2,...100\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $$n\mid \sum_{i=1}^ni^k \quad \forall k\in \{1,2,...,99\}$$

Prove that $n$ is not divisible by any number in the set $\{2,...99,100\}$.

This problem is from the book *Modern Olympiad Number Theory*. I'll present the solution given in the book,

Define $$S_\ell =\sum_{k=1}^nk^\ell $$

Such that $n\mid S_\ell\quad\forall\ell \in\{1,2,...,99\}$. Let $p$ be a prime in $\{2,3,...,100\}$ Then,

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{(n+1)^p-1}{n} &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^p-k^p \\ 
 &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} {p\choose i}k^i \\
&=1+\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}{p \choose \ell}\frac{S_\ell}{n}                       \end{aligned}$$

Since $p\mid {p\choose k}$ and $n\mid S_k$ we have $$\frac{(n+1)^{p}-1}{n}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
Now assume $p\mid n$ then the LHS becomes $$\sum_{k=1}^p(n+1)^{p-k}\equiv0\not\equiv 1\pmod p$$

Which is a contradiction. Thus, no prime in $\{2, 3, . . . , 100\}$ divides $n$.

So I have a few issues with this proof. First where did we use the fact that $k\in \{1,2,...,99\}$ or $p\in \{2,3,...,100\}$. Second, How would I think of $(n+1)^p-1/n$?

Comment: $n$ always divides $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k$ for any $k$. Doesn't it?

Comment: For any $k\in \{2,...,99\}$ @BobDobbs

Comment: @Bob, does $2$ divide $1+2$?

Comment: Question used $k$, solution used $l$...

Comment: @BobDobbs It doesn't matter. I think the author used $\ell$ to not confuse it with the index in the sum.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing that one of the expressions on the RHS relabels the index $i$ in $1 + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i} \frac{S_i}{n}$ to $k$ when $k$ was already used.

Comment: I'll relabel it @legionwhale

Answer (score 1):

The proof uses that $n | S_k$ for all $k = 1, ..., (p-1)$. Thus, if we only know that $n|S_k$ for $k \le 99$, we can only rule out prime divisors $p$ of $n$ for $p \le 100$.

As a corollary, this proves that there does not exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ divides $S_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What about the motivation behind $\frac{(n+1)^p-1}{n}$

Comment: @PNT Not sure, as I've never done olympiad maths. But the proof uses that it can also naturally be described as a sum of differences and a (finite) geometric series -- perhaps that is enough reason to consider it?